# Writing a SELECT statement to determine invalid values?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm taking a Database Design course online this semester, and this is my first time using SQL. I graduated with a degree in communications, but I'm taking certain computer science classes to help myself. We're using Microsoft SQL Server 2008, and I'm stumped on the last problem of our exercises. First 6 were a breeze (basic select functions, ordering the results, using aliases to rename tables, etc), but the last one deals with null values.

It states:

> Write a SELECT statement that determines whether the PaymentDate
>   column of the Invoices table has any invalid values. To be valid,
>   PaymentDate must be a null value if there's a balance due and a
>   non-null value if there's no balance due. Code a compound condition in
>   the WHERE clause that tests for these conditions.

Don't even know where to begin. Ha ha. I typically learn better in a classroom setting, but my schedule would not allow it with this course, so any explanation would help as well! Any help is appreciated!

Dave D.

---

So which one is correct? It's difficult to break it down when there's two different answers :) On my day off I'm gonna head to the professor's office so she can explain it to me in person anywho lol

Comment: How about you begin by showing us what the table(s) look like, then give it a shot. Please update your answer.

Comment: I'm probably going to make this very difficult but I'm not sure what you mean :( We're using SQL Server Management Studio and all the databases/tables were already attached. The columns include InvoiceID, VendorID, InvoiceNumber, InvoiceDate, InvoiceTotal, PaymentTotal, CreditTotal, TermsID, InvoiceDueDate and PaymentDueDate. InvoiceID is the primary key and according to the design, PaymentDate is the only column that allows null values.

Comment: Does "if there's Balance Due" mean "IS NOT NULL" or ">0"?

Answer (score 1):

The code below will select the records with invalid PaymentDate

```
SELECT * FROM Invoices WHERE (PaymentDate is not null and BalanceDue is not null) or (PaymentDate is null and BalanceDue is null)
```

Comment: If that's the case I was WAY overthinking it haha. When you're new to this it all seems so complicated. Just need to take a step back and jut read what its asking.

Comment: The expression `<> null` will always evaluate to false in SQL.  This answer is not correct.

Comment: You cannot compare to NULL and expect a meaningful result.  You need to use **IS NULL** or **IS NOT NULL** instead.

Answer (score 1):

Because there is an incorrect answer already posted, I'm going to walk through this.

This is a question of logic, that says that one of `PaymentDate` or `BalanceDue` are null.  In SQL, you test for NULL with the expression `IS NULL`.

So, the `where` clause for this would look like:

```
where (PaymentDate is null and BalanceDue is not null) or -- this is the first clause
      (PaymentDate is not null and BalanceDue is null)    -- this is the second clause
```

Any other comparison with a NULL value (=, <>, <, <=, >, >=, or in) return NULL boolean values, which are interpreted as FALSE.

Best of luck learning SQL.

Comment: Make sure to down-vote if incorrect answer still exists, please.

Comment: @NickVaccaro . . . I am very reluctant to downvote.  I will comment, however.

Comment: This "where" statement selects results where PaymentDate is valid so it does the opposite thing

Comment: Since it's not clear whether **BalanceDue** should be NOT NULL or positive value, it would be safer to use **COALESCE** or **NVL** functions.

Comment: I've read about COALESCE and NVL functions on my own, but we haven't gone over them in the text. This is the 3rd week. First week we basically introduced ourselves. Second week the problems provided us the queries, we just had to execute them and save them. This week we had to use write our own queries. 1st example was a basic select and order, 2nd one we had to change the name using aliases and use some addition and subtraction to create balances, etc. Had to create a new column using VendorFName and VendorLName. Last problem was this one using null values that I didn't understand :)